# How to drag and drop images into upload target of minus.com?

Tags: images, upload

I'm using this service to upload images: http://minus.com Is there a way to drag and drop images directly from another website into the "drag files here" area to upload? For now I need to download them first to my desktop to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

There's a `Select` hyperlink up at the top which will bring up a dialog box, which will allow you to upload in batch.  That way you can download all of the files onto your desktop from the other site, and then batch upload them to minus.

Hazarding a bit of a guess, I think what you are suggesting would be tricky due to measures against cross site scripting attacks.  Dragging something over from another website probably wouldn't have the proper information coming along with it.